# How do i remove remove SORT BY Price, Position, Name in Magento 2.1?

Tags: magento2, category, theme, sort

How do I remove the SORT BY Price, Position, Name in Magento 2.1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Do not understand why you want to remove/hide this options.
2. You can hide or remove this visibility as added.
3. If you are using any THEME, change the code in theme level.

/vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/list/toolbar/sorter.phtml

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

?>
<?php
/**
 * Product list toolbar
 *
 * @var $block \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar
 */
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\ProductList\Toolbar;
?>
<div class="toolbar-sorter sorter">
    <label class="sorter-label" for="sorter"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Sort By') ?></label>
    <select id="sorter" data-role="sorter" class="sorter-options">
        <?php foreach ($block->getAvailableOrders() as $_key => $_order): ?>
            <option value="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_key; ?>"
                <?php if ($block->isOrderCurrent($_key)): ?>
                    selected="selected"
                <?php endif; ?>
                >
                <?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__($_order)) ?>
            </option>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </select>
    <?php if ($block->getCurrentDirection() == 'desc'): ?>
        <a title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Set Ascending Direction') ?>" href="#" class="action sorter-action sort-desc" data-role="direction-switcher" data-value="asc">
            <span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Set Ascending Direction') ?></span>
        </a>
    <?php else: ?>
        <a title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Set Descending Direction') ?>" href="#" class="action sorter-action sort-asc" data-role="direction-switcher" data-value="desc">
            <span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Set Descending Direction') ?></span>
        </a>
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

**Replace to**

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

?>
<?php
/**
 * Product list toolbar
 *
 * @var $block \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar
 */
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\ProductList\Toolbar;
?>
<div class="toolbar-sorter sorter">
    <?php if ($block->getCurrentDirection() == 'desc'): ?>
        <a title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Set Ascending Direction') ?>" href="#" class="action sorter-action sort-desc" data-role="direction-switcher" data-value="asc">
            <span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Set Ascending Direction') ?></span>
        </a>
    <?php else: ?>
        <a title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Set Descending Direction') ?>" href="#" class="action sorter-action sort-asc" data-role="direction-switcher" data-value="desc">
            <span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Set Descending Direction') ?></span>
        </a>
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

> Not recommended to edit core module. create a new module/theme for use case.

Comment: how do you remove only `Position` from Sort by Option ? Can we do it without extending template and just by using xml or something ?

Comment: @Slimshadddyyy did you find a way to do this in the end? i'm trying to achieve the same thing

Comment: @John, you may extend the template in your custom theme and remove the `Position` option. You may also want to test it thoroughly

Answer (score 2):

You can use plugin for this case, because when you exclude the key in the template file, it will still sort the order of the products by position by default.

**Vendor/Module/Plugin/Magento/Catalog/Block/Product/ProductList/Toolbar.php**

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin\Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList;

class Toolbar
{
    public function aroundGetAvailableOrders(
        \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar $subject,
        \Closure $proceed
    ) {
        $result = $proceed();

        //make sure that each array key does exist, and then remove them
        if (array_key_exists('position', $result)) unset($result['position']);
        if (array_key_exists('name', $result)) unset($result['name']);
        if (array_key_exists('price', $result)) unset($result['price']);

        return $result;
    }
}
```

**Vendor/Module/etc/di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar">
        <plugin disabled="false" name="Vendore_Module_Plugin_Magento_Catalog_Block_Product_ProductList_Toolbar" sortOrder="10" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to remove only the "Position" option in the select you can edit your sorter.phtml in this way (don't edit core module, create a new module)

```
<select id="sorter" data-role="sorter" class="sorter-options">
        <option value="placeholder"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Sort By') ?></option>
        <?php foreach ($block->getAvailableOrders() as $_key => $_order):
            if ($_key == 'position'){ continue; }
            ?>

            <option value="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_key ?>"
                <?php if ($block->isOrderCurrent($_key)): ?>
                    selected="selected"
                <?php endif; ?>
                >
                <?= $block->escapeHtml(__($_order)) ?>
            </option>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </select>
```