# In magento2,Category Sorting Product list: How to remove position from attributes?

Tags: magento2, product-list, sorting

I have sorted products in categories by:

- price (default)
- name
- position

I need to remove the position from the menu leaving only price and name

I don't want to edit every single category view from the catalog-->manage categories because I have too many categories in the store.

PFA
[image]

Comment: you will need to customize in soter.phtml or use plugin for that but in plugin it will apply for all.

Comment: Please review https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/137112/how-do-i-remove-remove-sort-by-price-position-name-in-magento-2-1

Answer (score 8, accepted):

quick workaround can be add a condition in theme templates file **Magento_Catalog/templates/product/list/toolbar/sorter.phtml**
like

if $key != 'position' then don't add in drop down options :

```
<select id="sorter" data-role="sorter" class="sorter-options">
    <?php foreach ($block->getAvailableOrders() as $_key => $_order): ?>

        <?php if ($_key != 'position') : // if key sort by position remove it?>
        <option value="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_key ?>"
            <?php if ($block->isOrderCurrent($_key)): ?>
                selected="selected"
            <?php endif; ?>
            >
            <?= $block->escapeHtml(__($_order)) ?>
        </option>
       <?php endif; ?>

    <?php endforeach; ?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php $availableOrders = $block->getAvailableOrders();
            if(isset($availableOrders['position'])){
                unset($availableOrders['position']);
            }
        ?>
        <?php foreach ($availableOrders as $_key => $_order): ?>
            <?php //if ($_key != 'position') : // if key sort by position remove it?>
                <option value="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_key ?>"
                    <?php if ($block->isOrderCurrent($_key)): ?>
                        selected="selected"
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    >
                    <?= $block->escapeHtml(__($_order)) ?>
                </option>
            <?php //endif; ?>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
```